Examples of creating a TSOA custom success response for my POST endpoint
I've been looking to find how I might be able to implement a custom success response with TSOA for 201 and 202 responses, but haven't yet found any examples.  I'm new to TSOA and haven't found anything in the documentation, but I could have missed something. Is this something that can be done?
I have a basic POST endpoint such as this:
/**
   * @summary Create a new resource
   */
  @Post()
  @Response<ValidateError>(422, 'Validation Failed')
  @SuccessResponse('201')
  public async create(@Body() requestBody: NewRequest): Promise<NewRequest> {
    ... // code here for the endpoint.
  }

Can I change @SuccessResponse perhaps to use a custom response instead that would return a body as exampled below?
{
  "ACK": {
    "origin": "manager",
    "message": "request accepted",
    "id": "b6188a5f-9731-44a3-b942-315e4baf7dac"
  }
}


Any guidance would be really helpful. Thanks.
